# How to get rid of GNU GRUB menu

Tags: windows-7, grub, multi-boot

I had both windows 7 with UBUNTU installed on my laptop but long time ago, I tried to uninstall UBUNTU (I am not sure if I did it right!). I find this GNU GRUB menu really annoying now that I only want to boot to windows. How do I get rid of it? [This other question which seemed related didn't answer my question, and I have no windows boot disk.](https://superuser.com/questions/93179/is-it-possible-to-get-rid-of-grub)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible without recovery CD/DVD.

1. Reboot your computer
2. Select and <kbd>enter</kbd> Windows 7 in Grub menu
3. Press F8 to initiate Advanced boot options for Windows 7
4. Select `Repair Your Computer` from menu[image]
5. After logon to Account, Select `Command prompt` from menu [image]
6. Enter command `bootrec /fixmbr`
7. Exit command prompt and Restart your computer